# A proper title for e-mail and website address together?

Tags: copywriting, title

I am designing a journal and my native language is not English, though I have to have
the english translation for the same titles in my language. I have to put information of three companies in each page. Due to spacing problems I want to save space and put e-mail address and website addresses together.

Could you please suggest me a title that could possibly point to both of them and I could
be able to write both address in one line?

*I should remind that it is not a form and so it doesn't have inputs. I will fill in the information in journal pages and it will go for a mass print.*

Attached you can find a sample of what I am looking for which I choosed 'Interned Address' for that TITLE.

[image]

P.S. I would be really grateful if you could share a link which uses the same scheme.

Comment: If I had *spacing problems* the first thing to go would be the title itself. Simply "www.doe.com joe@doe.com" is perfectly self-explanatory.

Comment: The right place would be UX.stackexchange.com where you can expect interesting ideas. I myself would like to suggest something if you migrate the question there. ELU is hardly the place.

Comment: @ЯegDwight, thank you but it seems too much simplistic.

Comment: Everything should be made as simple as possible. Just not simpler.

Comment: I'm actually quite surprised this was migrated from English..

Comment: I would be very happy if a moderator decides were would be proper for this question?

Comment: Just to clear something up: are you looking for this to be part of a web form, as some answerers seem to have assumed, or are you looking for a way for you to represent this information when laying out information on a page?

Comment: I did mentioned in my question that I am asking it for a journal and BTW it is a paper journal. Thanks.

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean "put them on one line", could you post a mock up of what the relevant part of the form looks like?

Comment: I mean to have them in one line as you can find it in @TJH form though I am not designing a form and so it doesn't have inputs and the information will be printed in journal pages.

Comment: Mockup would still be helpful....I'm not actually seeing the need for a label here. If you're attaching a website/email to a person it should be extremely clear that www.blah.com is their site and name@example.com is their email

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This suggestion is almost embarrassing, but have you considered using:

[image: mockup]

<sup>[download bmml source](/plugins/mockups/download?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fXkub4.png) – Wireframes created with [Balsamiq Mockups](http://www.balsamiq.com/products/mockups)</sup>

Keep it simple and users will know what to do.

Comment: Yeah, even "Email/Web" would work, but I decided to know if there is any proper title in business literature for this purpose. After all both of them are ways of communicating with
the same organization

Comment: *facepalm* Why didn't I think of that?!

Comment: @TJH sometimes it's not good to try too hard. =)

Answer (score 3):

Since this is a printed document not a form with inputs I see no need for a label at all. Something like:

> Dilbertsoft
>   www.dilbert.com     dilbert@example.com

Is perfectly clear. Email/website are easily recognizable from their form alone, and unlike postal addresses there's no need for clarification as to where the address goes.

This doesn't work if you need multiple emails (support, recruitment, etc) or multiple sites (consumer, Business to Business) but it sounds like you only have one of each email/URL per company.

Answer (score 2):

Perhaps you could use

> Online Contact
>
> Online Contact Info [*informal*]
>
> Online Contact Information
>
> Online Addresses

or, if space is a problem, just

> Online Info

or even

> Online

Comment: Thank you very much for this useful reply, though I will be really grateful if you could please refer me to any available company/business with the same titling. e.g. any example!

Comment: @Naji I have not seen this particular configuration, probably because people tend to separate email from web addresses, since they are used for different purposes. Obviously some contacts will have one or the other or both, and if you are tight for space, your approach may work.

Comment: I had wanted to suggest exactly the same as bib -- that seems the most natural. Also, it is typically the case that the email address echoes the website, with only rare exceptions as in OP's example. Let's wait for more suggestions down the line, though.

Comment: I appreciate both of you and I also want to see more suggestions.

Comment: @Naji Or even "www/email"

Answer (score 2):

Have you thought about Icons? Combine them with placeholder text to make it super easy for the user

[image: mockup]

<sup>[download bmml source](/plugins/mockups/download?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fbSuJ2.png) – Wireframes created with [Balsamiq Mockups](http://www.balsamiq.com/products/mockups)</sup>

Comment: I'm fairly sure the question isn't looking for an input method (I'm assuming that's what you're going for here).

Comment: It doesn't seem to me it needed a minus vote and your answer was helpful though as I mentioned, I prefer the title. Thank you. (Sorry I don't have the permission to vote for users)

Comment: @dhmholley Was simply using inputs as a display example, same applies to outputs - wasn't suggesting input method as I'm sure Naji has this covered! Naji If you're looking for a text title I guess go with the above, and if it is an input - Which I promise I'm not saying it has to be! ;) - maybe you could add a placeholder as an example to the users in case the title isn't clear enough

Comment: Ah, I see. When you mentioned placeholder text and used text inputs I assumed you meant for the text to be editable.

Comment: @TJH: I'd strongly suggest not using an envelope as an icon for "street address" since it's used fairly often as a metaphor for "eMail". I'd suggest using a "house" icon instead.

Comment: Not a problem @dhmholley - easily done!

Comment: @TJH I don't understand what do you mean by input, but if that means that someone will fill in, I should say NO. I am currently designing to send it for mass print as paper journal,

Comment: I should mention that using icons and text titles in a same passage doesn't seem too much harmonic to me and that would be another reason for looking for a text title and not an Icon, though thanks.

Answer (score 1):

If you are filling in the information yourself and not expecting others to fill it in, like you stated I think that "Web Contact" would be sufficient:

**Web Contact: www.website.com  ,  email@email.com**

A url and an email address both have a distinct enough format that people will know what they are.